Lost USB connection on Windows 11
So I just bought a KVM switch for my desktop gaming pc and work laptop (both with windows 11). Everything was going great, I test both sides and it works. But after 3-4 switches between laptop and gaming pc, at some point I noticed the keyboard and mouse on the gaming pc was not working anymore. And even if I unpluged/pluged them again, no effect. when I switch back to laptop they work perfectly.
I thought at first the KVM switch was the one to blame but I did a test. I plugged directly the mouse/keyboard through a usb hub to the gaming pc. I unplugged/plugged 3-4 times the usb hub and it was the same effect, they went inactive. And the only way to fix it was to reboot the pc. I updated all the drivers of my motherboard, flashed the bios with new version, changed some settings on windows but no fix.
But then I booted the pc with ubuntu. there was absolutely no problem with it. and tried the kvm switch, it was perfect.
So I feel windows 11 is to blame ? maybe I installed something that caused this weird issue. I want to reinstall windows but I'm not 100% sure it will fix it. could it be shitty drivers of my motherboard for windows ? (MSI Z690-A WIFI)
What do you think ?
